# OpenGL crashes when trying to use glDrawArraysInstanced()

Tags: c++, opengl, crash, nvidia, vbo

Load to VAO function

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &modelVertexVBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &sphereTransformVBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, modelVertexVBO);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * (sphereModel->numVertices * 3), &(sphereModel->vertices[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereTransformVBO);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * (maxSphereStorage * 4 * 4), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4 * 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribDivisor(sphereTransformVBO, 1);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Geometry drawing function:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawArraysInstanced(sphereModel->mode, 0, sphereModel->numVertices, sphereCount);
```

When I try running this code it crashes with the following crash note:
    Exception thrown at 0x0000000068F4EDB4 (nvoglv64.dll) in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

When I remove the second VBO it works for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4 * 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
> ```

Your crash is the result of a simple copy-and-paste bug. You use attribute 0 here, which means you never called `glVertexAttribPointer` for attribute 1. Therefore, it uses the default attribute state, thus leading to a crash.

However, I strongly suspect that you are attempting to pass a 4x4 matrix as a single attribute. That won't work; OpenGL will [give you a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) if you try to set the attribute's size to be more than 4.

[Matrices are treated as arrays of (column) vectors](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Inputs). And each vector takes up a *separate* attribute index. So if you want to pass a matrix, you will have to use 4 attribute indices (starting with the one provided by your shader). And each one will have to have the divisor set for it as well.

Comment: the first bug was not actually a bug, when pasting to the website i accidentally changed the 1 to 0. just so you won't think i'm stupid XD

Comment: would incorrect `size` in `glVertexAttribPointer()` cause `Access violation reading` error?

Comment: I don't know, I'm currently checking if it matters.

Comment: @Harish: "*would incorrect size in glVertexAttribPointer() cause Access violation reading error?*" Not directly. In the event of most OpenGL errors, no state is changed. So it is as if it hadn't been called it at all. Which means it's the same problem, just done a different way.

Comment: I thought `glDrawArraysInstanced()` would cause the error as it tried to read beyond his second buffer.

Comment: @Harish: It's causing a crash because there's no buffer attached to an enabled array, so it tries to use a NULL CPU memory pointer.

Comment: @NicolBolas Doesn't glBufferData() with NULL pointer create a new storage buffer of said size but not care about values? I don't think it is accessing a null pointer there.

Comment: @NicolBolas I checked both conditions and incorrect `size` produces slightly different error `(nvoglv64.dll) in Sample.exe: An unhandled exception` and exceeding the buffer size produces the error in question `(nvoglv64.dll) in Sample.exe: Access violation reading`. While both answers are correct I believe mine is a more direct answer and yours prevents a follow up question from @GonnenDaube. Thanks its clearer now.

Comment: @Harish: "*Doesn't glBufferData() with NULL pointer create a new storage buffer of said size but not care about values?*" That has nothing to do with this. Unless `glVertexAttribPointer` successfully executes, no buffer object is ever associated with attribute 1. And if no buffer object is associated with an enabled attribute, then you get the pre-VBO default behavior: it pulls array data from a CPU pointer. A pointer who's default value is NULL.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think I'll probably ask this in another question since my tests show a different result. I see no crash if i call `glVertexAttribPointer()`with `size` as `5` which is clearly invalid. Incorrect vertices are drawn on the screen with `glDraw*()` which returns `GL_INVALID_VALUE` as expected, but there is no crash, which indicates that the buffer is valid with garbage values. But if the count exceeds the size of the VBO in `glBufferData()` the program crashes with `access violation` error.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you remapping the Vertex Attribute pointer to your second vbo?

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
...
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4 * 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
```

refer https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml for more info on `glVertexAttribPointer()`

I am guessing your draw call

```
glDrawArraysInstanced(sphereModel->mode, 0, sphereModel->numVertices, sphereCount);
```

> Note the '0' index in both cases

is exceeding the size of your second VBO and hence the error. Is this intentional that you want to remap your vertex attribute pointer to the second VBO? This overwrites the first mapping, in other words your first VBO is not being used.

I suggest using `GLuint attribute1;` to store the index and map accordingly to avoid such problems in future. Using numbers for attribute index directly like `0` is an easy way to make mistakes like this.

Comment: I accidentally made a mistake when pasting to the website and changed the 1 to 0.